# Create PATH for OS X Python virtualenv install

Tags: macos, terminal, path, .bash-profile

I'm a Terminal and Python newbie, but I'm using `virtualenv` a lot right now for a Python project.

Changing directories manually to source the `virtualenv` in my filesystem is quite tedious, so I'm looking for a way to speed up that process.

If I understand it correctly, I can edit `.bash_profile` and create a link to my `virtualenv` directory.

I've located the `.bash_profile` file and I'm just wondering, if my assumptions are correct and how to go about in adding the link to the `virtualenv` directory `py27` to `PATH`.

Manually I do this:
`source /bla/bla/bla/py27`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I solved it. The solution does not involve exporting a `$PATH` that loads automatically on Terminal/Bash startup, but rather uses an alias command to activate the virtual environment.

1. Open in text editor: `~/.bash_profile` (hidden file in User home directory).
2. Add an alias to start up virtualenv with the desired virtual environment of Python:

   `alias start_my_virtualenv="cd /path/to/the/virtual/python/bin; source activate"`
3. Quit and restart Terminal.
4. `start_my_virtualenv` will first go to the location of the Python environment, and then do `source activate` to activate that particular environment.

If you want to keep multiple Python environments, you can easily set up other aliases in the same manner to activate them.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write the same that you do in your terminal on your `.bash_profile`. If you type `source /bla/bla/bla/py27` on your terminal, wrote that line at the end of your `.bash_profile` will be enough.

Comment: Can you give an example? I understand that I need to enter the path somehow, it's how to do that I'm wondering about.

Comment: An example path in my bash_profile looks like this: `export PATH="/bla/bla/Python/Installs/miniconda/bin:$PATH"`

Comment: Type `which virtualenv` on a terminal and paste the result. Then edit `PATH` line on `.bash_profile` to looks like this: `export PATH="/bla/bla/Python/Installs/miniconda/bin:/paste-the-previous-copied-path:$PATH`.